# ignore spaces and dashes in javascript search code

Tags: javascript

I've got a search box where as I type, table data gets filtered through and only matching results get shown.  It works great; however, I want to make it better.

I want the code to ignore spaces and dashes.  I'd prefer make it easy to add additional characters I want it to ignore as well in the future..

For instance...

`Product Table
FH-54
TDN 256
TDN25678
FH54`

In the search box, if I type `FH54`, I'd like both the `FH-54` and the `FH54` to show up.  If I type in `FH-54` I'd also like the `FH54` and the `FH-54` to show up and so on to include `FH 54` as well.

If I type in `TDN2` or `TDN 2` in the search box, I'd like `TDN 256` and `TDN25678` to show up.

---

```
<b>Product Search</b><br /><form class="formatted">
<input id="Search" data-class="search_product" type="text" /></form>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $('#Search').on('keyup', function(e) {
  $("#noData").remove();
  var value = $(this).val();
  value = value.replace(/\\/g, '');
  var patt = new RegExp(value, "i");
  var sw = 0;
  var counter = 0;
  $('#Data tbody').find('tr').each(function() {
    counter++;
    if (!($(this).find('td').text().search(patt) >= 0)) {
      $(this).not('#header').hide();
      sw++;
    } else if (($(this).find('td').text().search(patt) >= 0)) {
      $(this).show();
    }
  });
  if (sw == counter) {
    $("#Data tbody").append(`<tr id="noData">
                  <td colspan="3">No data</td>
                </tr>`);
  } else {
    $("#noData").remove();
  }
});
        </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to reconstruct your scenario the best I could and made a working example.

As per your requirement to ignore all spaces and dashes: How about removing spaces and dashes from search string and from your values within the columns?

```js
$('#Search').on('keyup', function(e) {
    $("#noData").remove();
    var value = $(this).val();
    var spacesAndDashes = /\s|-/g;
    value = value.replace(spacesAndDashes, "");
    var patt = new RegExp(value, "i");
    var sw = 0;
    var counter = 0;
    $('#Data tbody').find('tr').each(function() {
        counter++;
        if (!($(this).find('td').text().replace(spacesAndDashes, "").search(patt) >= 0)) {
            $(this).not('#header').hide();
            sw++;
        } else if (($(this).find('td').text().replace(spacesAndDashes, "").search(patt) >= 0)) {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
    if (sw == counter) {
        $("#Data tbody").append(`<tr id="noData">
                <td colspan="3">No data</td>
                </tr>`);
    } else {
        $("#noData").remove();
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<b>Product Search</b>

<br />

<form class="formatted">
    <input id="Search" data-class="search_product" type="text" />
</form>

<table id="Data">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product Table</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>FH-54</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TDN 256</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>FH54</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>FH 54</td>
        </tr>            
        <tr>
            <td>TDN25678</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```